# Truncation error when import excel file to Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, import, truncation

I receive a truncation error(Copied and pasted below) when I try to import an excel document into Microsoft SQL Server that is running on my server. I don't understand this completely, but would love some help. Here is the error I receive and a bit more information at the bottom:

> - Executing (Error) Messages Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with output column "PSUNotes" (42) on output "Excel
>     Source Output" (9). The column status returned was: "Text was
>     truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code
>     page.

(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "output column "PSUNotes"
>   (42)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row
>   disposition on "output column "PSUNotes" (42)" specifies failure on
>   truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the
>   specified component.

(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source
>   - tblClient" (1) returned error code 0xC020902A.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().
>   The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the
>   error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

The excel table I am importing is called "tblClients" and the column "PSUNotes" is where the truncation error is occurring. I figured that the "(42)" in "PSUNotes" meant the error was column "PSUNotes" and row 42 in the excel file, but, after looking, that line is no more than 30 characters long. Other below and above have larger amount of data in them. So I have no clue whats going on.

Comment: Are you importing to an existing table? This error looks like the destination is too small. 
If so, try importing to brand new table.
Please post what version of SQL Server and Excel you are using.

Comment: The 42 just tells you the internal column ID assigned to that column by SSIS. You can't detect which row is causing the error using the Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the length of the Column to 500 or something and then try importing the data. Sometimes its difficult to narrow down the exact row causing the error.

Comment: I have the output for all the columns that are possible to be larger than 50 set to 1000. So i don't understand.